# How to deploy VM with thick provisioned Eagerly zeo disk type using HTML client?

Tags: webclient, vmware, vsphere, esxi

Upto ESXi 6.0, I was using legacy C# based Desktop client to deploy my VMs.
For the deployment, I was using Thick provisioned Eager Zero disk type.

Now I am using ESXi 6.5u1 and embedded HTML client to manage this host.
During the deployment steps VMware ask to choose disk as thin or thick and I am using thick option to deploy my VM.

**My Question**

When i am using thick disk type, VM is deployed but disk become thick provisioned lazy zero.
**Can anyone help me to know how to deploy VM with thick provisioned eager zero disk type.**

Thanks in advance !!!!

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are using at least mid-size environment, the quickest way is to deploy a VM, and then perform storage-VMotion. Storage-VMotion menu allows you chose VMDK format after the operation is done.

Answer (score 0):

During one of the 'customize settings' step of the VM deployment process, expand the hard disk/s and make the change to the option you would prefer. [image: Disk Provisioning Options as part of Step 4. Customize settings]